# batch - Directory of the currently processed file in batch

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I'm trying to use an unpacker to extract multiple files. My script goes like this

```
for /R %%i in (*.ext) DO quickbms.exe -o script.bms "%%i" "%%~ni"
```

The problem is when I drop a file from `C:\archives` it extracts all files to that directory, including the archives in `C:\archives\dir1`, `C:\archives\dir2`, `etc.`

How do I extract all archives in their own folder without having to manually start the script in each folder?

Comment: So `%%~ni` should represent the folder, right?

Comment: `for /R %%i in (*.ext) DO quickbms.exe -o script.bms "%%i" "%%~dpni"`

Comment: I ended up using `for /R %%i in (*.ext) DO quickbms.exe -o script.bms "%%i" "%%~pi\%%~ni"` @JosefZ, your version is a bit tidier, though, and does the same thing. Could you, please, post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /R %%i in (*.ext) DO quickbms.exe -o script.bms "%%~i" "%%~dpni"
```

Please read `for /?`: *The modifiers can be combined to get compound results*.

By [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html):

> - …
> - `%~f1` Expand `%1` to a Fully qualified path name - `C:\utils\MyFile.txt`
> - `%~d1` Expand `%1` to a Drive letter only - `C:`
> - `%~p1` Expand `%1` to a Path only e.g. `\utils\` **this includes a trailing `\`** which will be interpreted as an escape character by
>     some commands.
> - `%~n1` Expand `%1` to a file Name without file extension `C:\utils\MyFile` or if only a path is present (with no trailing
>     backslash) - the last folder in that path.
> - …

Your `"%%~pi\%%~ni"` would result (in terms of above examples) to `\utils\\MyFile.txt` (note two consecutive `\\` *reverse solidi*). 
Fortunately, batch interpreter considers doubled `\\` (and even multipled) backslash in a path as a single `\` *reverse solidus*…

Comment: Thanks for the link! I needed that.